# Forefront TMG denied connection using HTTPS listener

Tags: microsoft-ftmg-2010

I have configured a web publishing rule to allow access to an internal server over HTTP.  When i publish the rule everything works as expected.
When I change the rule to use a HTTPS listener, the rule seems to be ignored and I am getting the default rule applied. This results in:

```
Denied connection

Log type: firewall service
Status: The policy rules do not allow the user request
Rule: default rule
Source: External
Destination: Local Host (192.168.0.10:443)
Protocol: HTTPS
```

Everything looks right on the listener.
This setup is a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM on a dual-homed Hyper-V server (and it's a UAG install if that makes a difference).

Any thoughts?

Comment: 192.168.0.10 is TMG's IP or Webserver's IP?

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to route the traffic to the local host according to that message. By default TMG had a very very restricted list of rules for accessing local host.

I suspect this is wrong - it should be trying to forward to your web server; I suspect while you were in there something happened to the forwarding rule. That, or somehow your web server had ended up on the "local host" network set (although I'm not sure how as it's not normally user modifiable).